# Vue computed property not update

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a computed property en the same component that not updating.

In the component props is updated from Store states.

Look at first cuepoint : "visited": true

component props after store commits:

```
{
    "id": "1528877976193",
    "name": "I",
    "background": "null",
    "url": "I/",
    "videoSD": "HM_2v_0_1_1.mp4",
    "videoHD": "HM_2v_0_1_1_hd.mp4",
    "destination": "null",
    "cuepoints": [
        {
            "resource": "I/T00_S01_SC01_SL01_01.png",
            "sec": 20,
            "sequences": {
                "sequence": {
                    "resource": "I/T00_S01_SC01_SL01_01",
                    "second": "0"
                }
            },
            "type": "image",
            "visited": true
        },
        {
            "resource": "I/T00_S01_SC01_SL02_01.png",
            "sec": 109,
            "sequences": {
                "sequence": {
                    "resource": "I/T00_S01_SC01_SL02_01",
                    "second": "109"
                }
            },
            "type": "image",
            "visited": false
        }
    ]
}
```

But my computed proprety not updating:

```
  isBlank() {
    return this.data.cuepoints[0].visited === true ? false : true
  },
```

I'm tried with @mentorgashi no cache sugestion and nothing...

```
    lank_2: {
      cache: false,
      get: () => {
    this.data.cuepoints[0].visited === true ? false : true
      },
    },
```

thanks

Comment: can you show more of your code? When did you inspect / log the result? Have you tried `return this.currentSlide.active` ?

Comment: From your question i suspect you never registered the object into vue getter setter logic. Why do you expect it to be reactive? Pls show more.

Comment: in short, you can try telling vue to not cache your computed properties like:

`computed: {
 something: {
   cache: false,
   get() { return "Something not cached"; }
 }
}`

Comment: Hi @FrankProvost I post the code below..

Comment: You should edit your question and not post an answer - also remove the code that is irrelevant - show us your store for example and your data definition

Comment: Do you use the computed prop in a component template?